# Ninject And Connection Strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, ioc-container, ninject

I am very new to Ninject and am trying Ninject 2 with MVC and Linq. I have a SqlProductRepository class and all I want to know is what's the best way of passing the connectionstring in the constructor if I am injecting the Repository object in the controller.

```
public class SqlProductRepository:IProductRepository
{
    private Table<Product> productsTable;

    public SqlProductRepository(string connectionString)
    {
      productsTable = (new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<Product>();   
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> Products
    {
        get { return productsTable; }
    }
}
```

This is my ProductController class where I am injecting the Repository:

```
  public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private int pageSize = 4;
    public int PageSize { get { return pageSize; } set { pageSize = value; } }  

    IProductRepository _productsRepository;

    [Inject]
    public ProductsController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        _productsRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List(int page)
    {
        return View(_productsRepository.Products
                                       .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                                       .Take(pageSize)
                                       .ToList()
                    );
    }
}
```

Can somebody please guide me regarding this?

Answer (score 15):

You can set it up in your binding

```
_kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>()
       .To<SqlProductRepository>()
       .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString",yourConnectionString );
```

Answer (score 5):

You're doing:

```
new DataContext(connectionString)
```

in your code - this is the very newing and binding to classes you're trying to push out of your code by using a DI container. At the very least, consider adding an `IConnectionStringSelector` interface or something like that. You dont want to have 20 `Bind` calls for 20 repositories - you want a higher level abstraction than that.

I'd suggest the best solution is that you should be demanding either an `IDataContext` or an `IDataContextFactory` in the constructor instead and letting that worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

You could supply the connection string as a constructor argument when binding the `SqlProductRepository` to the `IProductRepository` interface.

```
public class LinqToSqlModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IProductRepository>().To<SqlProductRepository>()
            .WithConstructorArgument(connectionString, "connectionstring");
    }
}
```

I would suggest a slightly different approach. First of all, you might want to create a binding for the `DataContext` class in the kernel. You could do so by using a provider class to create your `DataContext` passing the connection string as an argument to its constructor. Then you bind the `DataContext` to the `DataContextProvider`.

```
public class DataContextProvider : Provider<DataContext>
{
    protected override DataContext CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        string connectionString = "connectionstring";
        return new DataContext(connectionString);
    }
}

public class LinqToSqlModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<DataContext>().ToProvider<DataContextProvider>();
        Bind<IProductRepository>().To<SqlProductRepository>();
    }
}
```

Next modify the constructor of `SqlProductRepository` class to accept a `DataContext` object instead.

```
public class SqlProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private readonly DataContext context;

    public ProductRepository(DataContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> Products
    { 
        get { return context.GetTable<Product>(); }
    }
}
```

By the way you don't have to decorate your constructor with the `Inject` attribute. Ninject will select the constructor with the most parameters by default.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code snap:

```
    //Bind the default connection string
    public void BindDataContext()
    {
        ConstructorArgument parameter = new ConstructorArgument("connectionString", "[Config Value]");
        Bind<DataContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope().WithParameter(parameter);
    }
    //Re-Bind the connection string (in case of multi-tenant architecture)
    public void ReBindDataContext(string cn)
    {
         ConstructorArgument parameter = new ConstructorArgument("connectionString", cn);
         Rebind<DataContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope().WithParameter(parameter);
    }
```

For more information, please visit below link

[MVC3, Ninject and Ninject.MVC3 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632592/mvc3-ninject-and-ninject-mvc3-problem/8446194#8446194)