# Ninject UOW pattern, new ConnectionString after user is authenticated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, authentication, connection-string, repository-pattern

I wonder if any one can point me in the right direction?

I am using the UOW repository pattern and have my dependencies injected via Ninject. I have a UnitOfWorkMapping class which inherits from NinjectModule, which I use to bind my IUnitOfWork to a concrete implementation of Dbcontext, see below

```
public class UnitOfWorkMapping : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IUnitOfWork>()
            .To<WebsiteDbContext>()
            .InRequestScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument(
                "connectionString",
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringKeys.UnauthorisedUser]
                    .ConnectionString);

        // Objects that explicitly need a DB context for the life of the request
        Bind<IUnitOfWorkInRequestScope>()
            .To<WebsiteDbContext>()
            .InRequestScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument(
                "connectionString",
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringKeys.UnauthorisedUser]
                    .ConnectionString);

        // Objects that specificall need a DB context for the life of the application
        Bind<IUnitOfWorkInApplicationScope>()
            .To<WebsiteDbContext>()
            .InSingletonScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument(
                "connectionString",
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringKeys.UnauthorisedUser]
                    .ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

So this gets called when the application starts and provides my site user with a context for an unauthorised user. This context has a database connection which connects to a database User which has limited access to the database objects.

Once the user has logged in to site I would like to switch to another connection which will give the context access to a Database user with wider access to the database objects.

So by the time the code execution reaches the true condition block for "if (Request.IsAuthenticated)" it is already using the "authorised" database connection for the context.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the PostAuthenticateRequest event of the Application control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String[] roles;
        var applicationConfiguration =
            (IApplicationConfiguration)
                DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IApplicationConfiguration));
        var identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var roleRepository =
                (IRoleRepository)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IRoleRepository));
            roles = roleRepository.GetRolesForUser(identity.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            roles = new[] { applicationConfiguration.UnknownUserRoleName };
        }
        var webIdentity = new WebIdentity(identity, roles);
        var principal = new WebsitePrincipal(webIdentity)
        {
            ApplicationConfiguration = applicationConfiguration
        };

        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    }
```

I haven't been able to find a code example on the net that is close enough to my code to adapt and implement. Please can any one advise? Thank you in advance.

A link to the complete code can be provided if required.

**Solution:**
Ok, so with the tireless help of Erik we have got there. The solution I am using is as so..

```
public class UnitOfWorkMapping : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        // Bind the IUnitOfWork for a user that is not logged in.
        Bind<IUnitOfWork>()
            .To<WebsiteDbContext>()
            .When(request => IsUserAuthenticated(request))
            .WithConstructorArgument(
                "connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringKeys.MainUserConnectionString]
                    .ConnectionString);

        // Bind the IUnitOfWork for a user that is not logged in.
        Bind<IUnitOfWork>()
            .To<WebsiteDbContext>()
            .When(request => !IsUserAuthenticated(request))
            .WithConstructorArgument(
                "connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringKeys.UnauthorisedUser]
                    .ConnectionString);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if the user authenticated.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The Ninject Activation request.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// returns <c>true</c> if the user exists and is authenticated
    /// </returns>
    public Boolean IsUserAuthenticated(IRequest request)
    {
        return (
            (HttpContext.Current.User != null) &&
            HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
    }
}
```

I hope that helps someone not spend days trying to get to the bottom of this issue.

Comment: Wow, you really don't understand Dependency Injection.  You're doing it in exactly all the ways you shouldn't be.

Comment: Exactly all of the ways?! Wow, thanks for the useful advice Erik.

Comment: I have now added the following the method by vrluckyin, here and that seems to be getting me somewhere...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632592/mvc3-ninject-and-ninject-mvc3-problem/8446194#8446194

Comment: If you're calling GetService, you're doing it wrong.  You're doing service location, not dependency injection.  Service Location is considered by many to be an anti-pattern

Comment: Thank you, that is a bit more helpful than "You're doing it in exactly all the ways you shouldn't be".

Comment: Not only that, but you should never, ever make a DbContext a singleton scope object in a web application.  DbContexts are not thread safe, and multiple users manipulating such a DbContext will cause unreliability at best, total data corruption at worst, and possible crashing.

Comment: You also shouldn't be using different interfaces for the same thing.  You should use contextual binding to choose which mapping to use to the same interface.  See https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use different bindings for whether a user is logged in or out, it's very simple.

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>()
   .To<WebsiteDbContext>()
   .When(x => !HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
   .InRequestScope()
   .WithConstructorArgument(
       "connectionString",
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringKeys.UnauthorisedUser]
           .ConnectionString);

Bind<IUnitOfWork>()
    .To<WebsiteDbContext>()
    .When(x => HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    .InRequestScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument(
        "connectionString",
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringKeys.AuthorisedUser]
           .ConnectionString);
```

Note that these both have the same IUnitOfWork binding, it will simply return the correct one based on whether the user is logged in or not.

I would also do this:

```
Bind<IIdentity>()
    .To<WebIdentity>()
     ...

Bind<IIdentity>()
    .ToMethod(x => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity)
    .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(WebIdentity))
    ...

Bind<IPrincipal>()
    .To<WebsitePrincipal>()
    ...
```

Then, configure your WebsitePrincipal's constructor to take IIdentity and IApplicationConfiguration parameters, make WebIdentity's constructor take IIdentity and IRoleRepository as  parameters (note the .WhenInjectedInto uses the existing Identity).  Have your constructors do the work.

Then you need only write the following (DI takes care of the rest):

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.User = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IPrincipal));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at implementing that approach.

Comment: I have started to have a look at implementing this, but can any one advise which namespace ".When(...)" exists in?

I have imported "Ninject.Syntax" but that still does not compile.

I'm using:
    Ninject            v3.0.0.0
    Ninject.Web.Common v3.0.0.0
    Ninject.Web.Mvc    v3.0.0.0

Comment: @Dib -  Those are all very old versions.. the latest is 3.2.1.0.  Did you install Ninject.MVC3 with Nuget?  You shouldn't need anything other than what Ninject.MVC3 installs.

Comment: Thanks I'll download that version tomorrow. I'm not a fan of using nuget. It messes up the folder structure. I'd rather put the dlls in a place I chose!

Comment: @Dib - So, you would rather spend days beating your head against the wall, fighting problems that would never have happened if you had used a standard package distribution, just because you're stubborn about where you put things?  You should really get with the program, Nuget isn't going away, and it makes your life a ton easier...

Comment: I now have the version 3.2.0.0 of Ninject and still ".WhenInjectedInto(...)" or ".When(...)" does not compile... Any further suggestions?

Comment: @Dib - Have you setup all the proper assembly redirection, and other configuration necessary? Again, if you had just used nuget, this would all be done for you...

Comment: I created a brand new ASP web project, and used nuget to get the package. Even in that the ".When(...)". I tried using the binding syntax with a System.String object. I still get the same error as I do with my interface and concrete implementation (albeit different types) "'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingNamedWithOrOnSyntax<string>' does not contain a definition for 'When' and no extension method 'When' accepting a first argument of type 'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingNamedWithOrOnSyntax<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" error...

Comment: Do I need to add any other references or "usings"? LinQ for instance?

Comment: @Dib - Why don't you just do this.. Create a new MVC project, add Ninject.MVC3 via NuGet, then do two things.  First, prove to yourself that the .When syntax works out of the box there.  Second, figure out what's different between it and your project.  Since we can't see your code, you're the only one that can do that.

Comment: Trying that now. The syntax does wok in the test project. Just doing the gap analysis now.

BTW, code is available here:
https://github.com/dibley1973/Dibware.Template.Presentation.Web

Comment: If I have this line in my project it works... "Bind<ICloneable>().To<String>().When(x => !HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated).InSingletonScope();"       However the example line you gave me up there does not.

Comment: Got it... "InRequestScope()" has to be after ".When(...)"

Comment: Erik, please can you edit your answer so it will be correct for anyone else who reads it, to save them days of pain like I have had?

Comment: I have just realised that I can edit the answer so have moved the "InRequestScope()" to below the ".When()"

Comment: Actually I spoke to soon.. running the code crashes on the line ".When(x => !HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)" as "Request is not available in this context"

Any further suggestions?

Comment: @Dib - Right, because you're in PostAuthenticateRequest, the Request isn't assigned to the HttpContext yet... I'm not sure if the Default IIdentity is authenticated yet, but you can try `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

Comment: Nah, User is null at that point. The problem is this code gets run very early in the request cycle. It is called before my MembershipProvider can be used, for instance...

Comment: @Dib - How is User null when your code above was using it?

Comment: Err.. because the code in "UnitOfWorkMapping" is called way before the code in "MvcApplication.Application_PostAuthenticateRequest", I guess....

Comment: @Dib - No, the When condition should be evaluated at the time the service is resolved.  It's an expression.  Otherwise, it would make the use of When rather pointless.

Comment: Well it is certainly happening before "MvcApplication.Application_PostAuthenticateRequest". It appears to be downstream of the call to "kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());" in "MvcApplication.CreateKernel"....       I am currently looking to see if .ToMethod(...) may help. very little on the web, unless my search terms are bad! May have to give up until tomorrow morning as it is getting late here.

Comment: @Dib - I just tested, and both using Request and User work just fine in a brand new MVC app with Ninject.MVC3 installed from NuGet in the PostAuthenticateRequest method.  You're obviously doing something that is causing the methods to be evaluated early.

Comment: @Dib, how are you loading your module?

Comment: @Dib - I just tested in a module, to see if that made a different, it still worked fine in a default MVC app with Ninject.MVC3 installed from Nuget, and using a Ninject module in which I call `kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())` in `RegisterServices()`.  I then call `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService()` in `PostAuthenticateRequest()`.  Try it for yourself.  Create a simple default MVC3 app, add Ninject.MVC3 from Nuget, create a simple Module with configuration similar to this.

Comment: Yep, got there in the end... I think the crux of it is using the .When(Func) method to call a method which evaluates the state of the User, including assuming a NULL user is an unauthenticated user.

Thanks for all your help over the last few days.

Comment: Full code here:   https://github.com/dibley1973/Dibware.Template.Presentation.Web/blob/master/Dibware.Template.Presentation.Web/Global.asax.cs   and  here: https://github.com/dibley1973/Dibware.Template.Presentation.Web/blob/master/Dibware.Template.Presentation.Web/Composition/UnitOfWorkMapping.cs

Comment: @Dib - User should not be null when unauthenticated.  Your problem is that you're doing things so wrong... You shouldn't be doing deriving your App from NinjectHttpApplication.  You shouldn't be doing everything in global.asax like that... That is all way out of date code that doesn't function correctly in more MVC